# Windows Explorer - is it possible to define an "Open with" application for a file without extension?

Tags: windows-explorer

The file name in question is "Vagrantfile".

I would love to be able to double-click it and have it opened in my favourite text editor. Unfortunately, Windows always chooses to ask me, what editor would I like. Always. I understand, that this is because this file has no extension, and by default, Windows thinks it can not choose a default application for it, but please... each and every time I choose the same application.

I know, that I can make a batch file, choose "Edit with Notepad++" from a right-click menu. I know I can create a shortcut, I know there is thousands of options.

But would it be possible to declare an application as a default file handler using the name of the file and not the extension?

The Windows in question is 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: no, I'm afraid that is not possible. What will work though, is creating a shortcut or batch script that launches the editor and opens the file all in one go, since you only want that behavior for one file.

Comment: What's stopping you from making up a new extension and associating it with a program? You should then be able to rename your file to *Vagrantfile.[your_extension]* and open it with a double-click.